# Rg.Plugins.Popup doesn't work only in release mode (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, apk

I am using Rg.Plugins.Popup and it's work fine in debug mode...but when I try the release mode or when I generate an apk it doesn't work. Did someone see something like that?
I guess the others plugins are not there as well

-------------- Update ----------------------

now it works in release mode with no reason, I dont Know why... but in installed apk it doesnt work

[image]

Comment: Are you using linker?

Comment: "sdk and user assemblies". Do I need to change that?

Comment: I guess it can be the reason. Make a try using "sdk only" or "none". If it works, you reduce your research to figure out what the linker is taking away and you need.

Comment: It's deployed only if "sdk and user assemblies" is selected.

Comment: I updated my question because it appeared when I selected ProGuard...but it doesn't occur in installed apk @DiegoRafaelSouza

Comment: It all is very weird. Looks like an inconsistency on the apk build proccess, like cache or some kind of trash. Try to use the `Device Monitor` to get any relevant information about this issue. I'm out of ideas too =/

Comment: I don't understand if it is a bug or somenthing like that..but, now it works...

Comment: I had the opposite issue. The Android project was building or release and throw an exception if run in debug mode. And similarly, after restarting, cleaning, and updating the visual studio, Xcode, .... It was resolved

Answer (score 1):

if i use proguard with linker my app crashes. I only select the sdk and user assemblies linker option & it works fine.

Comment: it's crazy...now, mine doesn't work with proguard option...but ok LOL